# How to draw a curve approximated to original one

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d

I have a set of points and i want to draw a curve which should be approximated to original curve.
Let say ,in hawk-eye system(used in cricket) i have a set ofco-ordinates of ball during    the entire flight of ball , now how can i draw such a curve going through ball's space co-ordinates and looks appromixately to original curve
one method i thought its to get a large number of points such that every two point
is very close to each other and then draw a straight light between them

Comment: You might want to read up on [interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation) in general and [polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation) or [spline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation) interpolation in specific. That should get you started. :)

Comment: @Bart is correct, you should look at the topics but you should consider also 3D space. I would tell you to have a look to a numerical analysis text book for the numerical methods and a calculus book for the basics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Curves are almost always rendered in four steps:

1. **Approximate or interpolate** a set of points using a curve or spline algorithm. Choices may include:

   - [Cubic splines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_%28mathematics%29), which pass through all of the data points and produce a smooth curve
   - [Bézier curves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_%28mathematics%29), which do not pass through all the points, but which lie within the envelope of the consecutive groups of 4 points surrounding each curve section.
   - [Hermite curves](http://www.cubic.org/docs/hermite.htm), which are defined by a set of points, and a set of tangent vectors: you would need to generate the set of tangent vectors somehow in order to use this sort of curve.
   - (and probably more that I've forgotten)
2. **Convert** whichever representation you chose to a [Bézier Curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#Computer_graphics): this can be achieved by a simple matrix transformation from other curve types.
3. [Repeatedly **subdivide**](http://mi.eng.cam.ac.uk/~gmt11/3g4/curves/Bezier_CurveCut_e.html) the Bézier curve: the control points tend to approximate the curve.
4. Draw the control points of the subdivided curve, joined by a straight line.

If you go straight for the Bézier curve, which is probably the easiest, then there are some very [simple and elegant methods of subdividing it](http://www.antigrain.com/research/adaptive_bezier/index.html#toc0003).

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend Catmull-Rom splines for this purpose, they are based on Hermite curves.  Rather than using 2 points and 2 tangents, it uses the four adjacent data points to interpolate making it better suited/simpler for motion path upsampling.

Comment: Knew I was forgetting one >.<